# Searching values of dictionary in Python in a class

Tags: python, dictionary, search, key

this is a pretty basic question but I'm not sure if my syntax is right here.

In my class, i have the following:

```
class Example:
    def method(self):
      self.rule = {}
      ... #code to fill dictionary here
      x = 'String'
      #want to search values of the dictionary for x
      if x in self.rule.values:
        return True
```

For some reason this isn't compiling for me and I think it's due to self.rule.values. What would be the proper way to search values of the dictionary self.rule in this situation?

Comment: You can just `return x in self.rule.values()` instead of returning returning true in the condition of the statement.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Yes I just put in ... as placeholders there for my actual code. So it turns out it was just a question of using () at the end, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are simply missing the brackets at the end of `values` -> `if x in self.rule.values()`

```
>>> {}.values
<built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f4c6dac5900>
>>> {}.values()
dict_values([])
```

Comment: Note, `...` is valid in python3. But I think op put  the '...' to indicate he is omitting extra code as it is not relevant to the question and would otherwise increase lines of code posted here.

Comment: @francium Yes, that's what I was doing. Thank you!

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce It was just a case of me forgetting the parentheses, thank you for the help!

Comment: Please mark this question as correct to be courteous to the poster

Comment: @francium Have done that! Thank you both for the responses

Comment: @TSH No problem, it happens to all of us!